# PL/SQL MYSQL ¿Por qué se duplican la misma respuesta en diferentes campos?

Tags: mysql, mysqlprocedure, mysql-cursores, mysql-procedimiento

> Crea un procedimiento que actualice el campo Total_Salarios y el campo Media_Salarios de la tabla Departamento, siendo el total la suma del salario actual de todos los empleados del mismo. Este procedimiento debe además calcular la media de los salarios del departamento y actualizar convenientemente el valor en la tabla departamento. Utiliza cursores.

Al lanzar el procedimiento, los campos `TotalSalario` y `MediaSalario` me dan el mismo valor, cosa que no debería ser así.
Al principio los campos `TotalSalario` y `MediaSalario` tenían el valor de 0.

```sql
delimiter $$
drop procedure if exists ejer2; $$
create procedure ejer2()
    begin
        declare vTotalSalario float;
        declare vMediaSalario float;
        declare fin int default 0;
        declare curEjer2 cursor for
            select sum(Salario), avg(Salario)
            from Tabla_Empleado
            group by Num_Depart;
        declare continue handler for not found set fin=1;
        open curEjer2;
        bucle: loop
            fetch curEjer2 into vTotalSalario, vMediaSalario;
            if fin=1 then   
                leave bucle;
            end if;
            update Tabla_Departamento
            set Total_Salarios=vTotalSalario, 
            Media_Salarios= vMediaSalario;

        end loop;
        close curEjer2;
        select * from Tabla_Departamento;
    end;
$$

call ejer2();
```

**Tabla Departamento**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tabla Empleado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es que eso no es asi exactamente, necesitas 2 o 3 variables y dentro del bucle suma los presupuestos o lo que deseas, lo divide por el numero de entradas al bucle y luego  te lo mostrara

Comment: Tengo una duda. ¿Cuándo se que tengo que usar cursores y cuando no y cuántos por que aquí me comentas que debo de usar 2 o 3? ¿En que debo basarme para saberlo.? Gracias.

Comment: Por lo que estoy viendo haces update pero en un cursor lo que hace es una tabla temporal por lo que con crear variable te lo solucionaría, otra cuestión es puedes poner el enunciado de tu ejercicio porque ese update me esta volviendo loco

Comment: Listo he actualizado la pregunta para que aparezca. Es que he estado haciendo otros ejercicios y aún que en otro no me da error al ejecutarlo, diría que esta mal, ya que, al igual que en este caso me sale la misma respuesta en filas diferentes del mismo campo.

Comment: Enrealidad estas usando cursores pero en los cursores puedes crear variables y utilizarla a tu antojo. Por ejemplo tu ya has creado variables como `` declare vMediaSalario float;`` pues crea una variable llamada contador con valor por defecto 0. ``declare contador int default 0`` luego dentro del bucle haces ``set contador = contador + 1`` con eso tendrás el número de veces que entra para dividir posteriormente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema reside en que no estás usando un `WHERE` en el `UPDATE` por lo que actualiza todos los elementos de la tabla, poniendo el último elemento cogido, en este caso el sueldo del director, el cual es 80000 y al ser solo una persona en el departamento, la media y el sueldo total son 80000.

Te adjunto el código del `procedure` solo:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE ejer2()
    BEGIN
        DECLARE vTotalSalario FLOAT;
        DECLARE vMediaSalario FLOAT;
        DECLARE idDep INT;
        DECLARE fin INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE curEjer2 CURSOR FOR
            SELECT SUM(Salario), AVG(Salario), Num_Depart
            FROM Tabla_Empleado
            GROUP BY Num_Depart;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET fin=1;
        OPEN curEjer2;
        bucle: LOOP
            FETCH curEjer2 INTO vTotalSalario, vMediaSalario, idDep;
            IF fin=1 THEN
                LEAVE bucle;
            END IF;
            UPDATE Tabla_Departamento
            SET Total_Salarios = vTotalSalario,
            Media_Salarios = vMediaSalario
            WHERE id = idDep;
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE curEjer2;
    END;
$$
```

Como puedes ver he añadido una variable `idDep` a la cual le meto el `Num_Depart` de la tabla `Tabla_Empleado` y después lo uso en el bucle para que actualice solo la línea del departamento correspondiente.

Quiero aclarar que estos cambios funcionan perfectamente, pero que hay muchas cosas en este script que no he usado nunca, por lo que igual existe alguna forma más sencilla de conseguir los `id` gracias al `cursor` o algo, pero la desconozco... Si existiera, la conoces y consigues añadirla, nos la comentas y aprendemos todos.